# Xcode - что за штука такая?

Tags: ios, xcode

Являюсь счастливым обладателем яблочных продуктов. Решил попробовать себя в области iOS-разработки. Как я понял, многое изменилось в Xcode с тех пор, когда пол года назад Яндекс записали небольшое введение в эту тему. Так вот, там красуется везде такая панель с элементами и они оттуда так классно перетаскивают кнопки со словами "Просто перетащите сюда". Но вот не задача, у меня нет такой панели и найти я ее не могу. Из-за абстракции ее названия я даже загуглить это нормально не могу. Почему у меня в Xcode эта панель не весит по-умолчанию? Где ее взять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сталкивался с тем, что панель бывает скрыта, нужно попытаться свернуть все до момента ее появления.

Answer (score 1):

Выяснил. Видимо произошли какие-то изменения (и довольно серьёзные). Всем, кому интересно. Это называется Controls and View Library. Чтобы выбрать необходимый вам элемент, есть два варианта: 
 - View -> Show Library
 - Комбинация Command + Shift + L

У меня все, всем спасибо